React Native Expo-Location : background Location updates stop a couple of seconds after launch on Android
Building an app that tracks the user's location every minute, using React Native and Expo Location. I use development builds and tried the app on actual devices. The app starts the tracking but it stops after a single update.
I use Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync and TaskManager.defineTask.
The app works fine on IOS. A very similar behavior (shutting down in a couple of seconds) happened with another library I tried to solve the problem (react-native-community/geolocation), which leads me to believe it is an Android thing.
Here's the code :
component.tsx
useEffect(() => {
    requestLocationPermissions().then((result) => {
      if (!result) return;
      backgroundLocationFetch();
    });
}, []);

export const requestLocationPermissions = async () => {
  let status =
    await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
  const sth = await Location.requestBackgroundPermissionsAsync();
  if (sth.granted && status.granted ) return true;
  else return false;
};

functions.ts
const backgroundLocationFetch = async () => { 
   Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync(LOCATION_TASK_NAME, {
    showsBackgroundLocationIndicator: true, 
    accuracy: Location.Accuracy.Balanced, 
    timeInterval: 5000, 
    distanceInterval: 40, 
    foregroundService: { 
      notificationTitle: "App", 
      notificationBody: "Getting your location", 
      killServiceOnDestroy: true, 
      }, 
   }); 
};


TaskManager.defineTask(LOCATION_TASK_NAME, async ({ data, error }) => { 
  if (error) { return; }
  if (data) {
 
    // fetching to server
    const response = await sendDataToServer(
      ...
      // the response arrives when called and can be logged
    );
  }
});

package.json
"expo-location": "~17.0.1",
"expo-task-manager": "~11.8.2",
"react-native": "0.74.2",
"expo": "~51.0.14",

